# AWK One-liner to compare file against blacklist file and remove offending lines

Tags: bash, awk

Ok so I have two text files.

File1 is tab delimited and has multiple columns, specifically it contains a column of values that I want to compare to File2. The file is not sorted in any way

File2 is a single column of values, aka the blacklist. It is shorter than File1 in length but is sorted.

I want to compare these two columns, one from each file, and if any values in File1 match File2, I don't want to print that line.

File1:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
val  val  34   val
val  val  110  val
val  val  24   val
val  val  300  val
val  val  55   val
```

File2:

```
24
34
55
```

Desired Output:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
val  val  110  val
val  val  300  val
```

So far I have this:

`awk -F '\t' '{i =1}NR==FNR{a[$3];next}{if($1 in a){print FNR,i++}}' File1 File2 > output.txt`

I'm kind of poking around in the dark and don't know how to get what I need out of it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I believe this is what I was looking for: `awk -F '\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} !($3 in a){print $0}' File2 File1 > Output.txt`

Comment: yes but get rid of the redundant `{print $0}` as that's the default action when a condition is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk you need to store the file2 in an array (using the field as a key and with a true value like 1) and then to test what returns `a[$3]` when the file1 is processed:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=1;next} !a[$3]' file2 file1
```

Comment: Hmm this seems to give me `a[: Event not found.` Would my comment above not work correctly? It seemed to give me a reasonable output?

Comment: @user3396810: probably because you have replaced single quotes with double quotes.

Comment: @user3396810 your shell is interpreting `!` as a history searching character, read your shell man page for how to disable that (or google it).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with two invocations of sed :

```
s=`sed -r 's+(.*)+/\1/ d+' fv2.txt` 
sed "$s" fv1.txt
```

The first build a sed script in `$s` from your second file which filters the lines from your first file when used in the second sed invocation.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
NR == FNR { skip[$1] = 1; next }
$3 in skip { next }
{ print }' File2 File1
```